# Python script for web scraping from web pages to find ip address for urls present in it

Tags: python, scripting, web-crawler

I have started writing script as mentioned below

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

trg_url='http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/'
req=urllib2.Request(trg_url)
handle=urllib2.urlopen(req)
page_content=handle.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_content,"html")
new_list=soup.find_all('a')


for link in new_list:
    print link.get('href')
```

but now i am stuck, as i am getting below mentioned output

```
http://mytimes.indiatimes.com/?channel=toi
https://www.facebook.com/TimesofIndia
https://twitter.com/timesofindia
https://plus.google.com/117150671992820587865?prsrc=3
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rss.cms
https://www.youtube.com/user/TimesOfIndiaChannel
javascript:void(0);
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com
javascript://
http://beautypageants.indiatimes.com/
http://photogallery.indiatimes.com/
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/videos/entertainment/videolist/3812908.cms
javascript://
/life/fashion/articlelistls/2886715.cms
/life-style/relationship/specials/lsspeciallist/6247311.cms
/debatelist/3133631.cms
```

please guide me to extract the different URLs present in web page and there IP address

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to extract URLs present in web page and print there IP address in a file.

Answer (score -1):

Use the socket module to get the ip address:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import socket
import csv

trg_url='http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/'
req=urllib2.Request(trg_url)
handle=urllib2.urlopen(req)
page_content=handle.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_content,"lxml")
new_list=soup.find_all('a')

final_list = []
for link in new_list:
    l = link.get('href')
    try:
        final_list.append([l,socket.gethostbyname(l.split('/')[2])])
    except:
        final_list.append([l,[]])

with open('output.csv','wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for row in final_list:
        wr.writerow(row)
```